# GTK4 Window Created From XML Immediately Closes

Tags: python, gtk, gtk4

I create a GTK4 Window from an XML file via Python.
When I run the code, the window actually pops up very briefly (and all controls are there as expected), but then closes immediately. I assume there is something missing in my code, but I can't figure out what it is from the documentation.

```
import sys
import gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '4.0')
gi.require_version('Adw', '1')

from gi.repository import Gtk, Adw


class MyApp(Adw.Application):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.connect('activate', self.on_activate)

    def on_activate(self, app):
        builder = Gtk.Builder()
        builder.add_from_file("main.glade")
        self.win = builder.get_object("window")
        self.win.present()

app = MyApp(application_id="com.example.GtkApplication")
app.run(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it :-)

The solution is a simple one-liner:

```
self.win.set_application(app)
```